# VSCode como setar a guia Open Editors fechada por padrão

Tags: visual-studio-code

Td vez que abro um programa novo no `VSCode` ele vem com essa 'guia' `Open Editors` aberta por padrão, parece só um detalhe, mas é mto ruim qd esqueço de fechar logo no inicio e qd vou ver já tem um monte de arquivos abertos e a guia do projeto mesmo foi deslocada lá pra baixo na tela...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que da pra sumir com ela add a configuração `"explorer.openEditors.visible": 0,` porem não quero remover a guia totalmente, pois preciso dela qd vou selecionar arquivos de fora do projeto para comparar... O que eu quero é alterar a configuração padrão para que o `VSCode` deixa essa guia `Open Editors` **fechada por padrão**.

Alguem sabe como fazer isso?

Obrigada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao lado do EXPLORER há (...) clica nele, em seguida é só remover a seleção (editores abertos). Pronto!

Comment: Opa, funcionou. Embora isso remova a pasta da lista tb, ela ainda fica disponível novamente nos (...), já no caso da configuração `"explorer.openEditors.visible": 0`, ela desaparecia completamente sem possibilidade de fácil localização. Obrigada.